# Reference version conflict in nuget package - bindingRedirect doesn't seem to work

Tags: google-api, nuget-package, google-api-dotnet-client

The nuget package `Google.Apis.Auth` adds a reference in my project to `Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices`, but the dll version from nuget is `1.9.1.12399` and it seems that `Google.Apis.Auth` needs version `1.9.1.12397` instead as you can see in the exception thrown below.

I tried to add `<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.9.1.12397" newVersion="1.9.1.12399" />` to app.config and machine.config but it won't work.

This is the exception:

```
    System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.1.12397, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or on
    e of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
    File name: 'Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.1.12397, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsyncCore>d__e.MoveNext()
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncTaskMethodBuilder`1.Start[TStateMachine](TStateMachine& stateMachine)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsyncCore(Initializer initializer, IEnumerable`1 scopes, String user, CancellationToken task
    CancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore)
       at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in c:\code\google.com\google-api-dotnet-client\default\Tools\Google.Apis.Release\bin\Debug\test\default\Src\GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4\OAuth2\GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.cs:line 59
    --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       at GoogleTasker.Program.<>c__DisplayClass4.<<Main>b__0>d__6.MoveNext() in c:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\GoogleTasker\GoogleTasker\Progr
    am.cs:line 29

 === Pre-bind state information ===
    LOG: DisplayName = Google.Apis.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.1.12397, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
     (Fully-specified)
    LOG: Appbase = file:///c:/users/user/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GoogleTasker/GoogleTasker/bin/Debug/
    LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
    Calling assembly : Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices, Version=1.9.1.12399, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.
    ===
    LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
    LOG: Using application configuration file: c:\users\user\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\GoogleTasker\GoogleTasker\bin\Debug\GoogleTasker.vshost.exe.Confi
    g
    LOG: Using host configuration file:
    LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
    LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/user/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GoogleTasker/GoogleTasker/bin/Debug/Google.Apis.PlatformServices
    .DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/user/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GoogleTasker/GoogleTasker/bin/Debug/Google.Apis.PlatformServices
    /Google.Apis.PlatformServices.DLL.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/user/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GoogleTasker/GoogleTasker/bin/Debug/Google.Apis.PlatformServices
    .EXE.
    LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///c:/users/user/documents/visual studio 2013/Projects/GoogleTasker/GoogleTasker/bin/Debug/Google.Apis.PlatformServices
    /Google.Apis.PlatformServices.EXE.
```

And this is my code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            Task.Run(async () =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                            new[] { "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/tasks" },
                            "user",
                            CancellationToken.None,
                            new FileDataStore("Store")
                        );
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                        throw;
                    }

                }
            );
        }
    }
```

App.config:

```
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Primitives" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.28.0" newVersion="4.2.28.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Google.Apis.Auth.PlatformServices" publicKeyToken="null" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.9.1.12397" newVersion="1.9.1.12399" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

Comment: This is weird, in our samples repository there are different versions of those dlls - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/blob/master/Drive.Sample/Drive.Sample.csproj. Can you please verify that you are using the latest version of NuGet and try to create a new project from the beginning?

Comment: It helps to look at your code one week later :) The error is actually a missing reference to "Google.Apis.PlatformServices". The reference being added is to "Google.Apis.**Auth**.PlatformServices". No idea there were several PlatformServices dll, that's why I was confused. Either way, shouldn't the install-package cmd pull that reference as well?

Comment: Google.Apis.PlatformServices is a different dll for each platforms (full dotnet profile, windows phone, windows store, etc.). When installing the Google.Apis and Google.Apis.Auth package, NuGet install the right dlls for you, take a look in this file - https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/blob/master/Tools/Google.Apis.Release/Resources/Google.Apis.VERSION.nuspec#L40 it might help you understand the different.

Comment: @peleyal Ok, I think that my problem came from installing only Google.Apis.Auth. I thought that Google.Apis was a dependency and it would have been installed automatically by nuget, but it didn't, at least not correctly. After installing both one after the other, it worked correctly!

Comment: Great! Why did you want to install only Google.Apis.Auth? Are you working with a specific API? If so, the API should have a dependency in Google.Apis.Auth and Google.Apis.

Comment: I just wanted to reuse the authentication part. I'm using Tasks and Calendar API, but I have a custom library for the REST calls. That's why I just added Google.Apis.Auth.

Comment: Don't you want to use the Google.Apis.Calendar and Google.Apis.Task NuGet packages?